# How can I reflect this value in the menu?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```js
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        // Tüm içerikleri gizle
        var allContents = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
        allContents.forEach(function (content) {
            if (!content.classList.contains('initially-hidden')) {
                content.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    });



    var groupId; // Global groupId değişkeni
    var deviceId;

    function showContent(contentId, currentGroupId,currentDeviceId) {
        var allContents = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
        allContents.forEach(function (content) {
            content.style.display = 'none';
        });

        groupId = currentGroupId;
        deviceId = currentDeviceId;// showContent çağrıldığında groupId'ı güncelle

        var selectedContent = document.getElementById(contentId);
        if (selectedContent) {
            selectedContent.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    function createAuthorizationGroups(count) {
        var authMenu = document.getElementById("subMenuAuth");
        authMenu.innerHTML = '';

        for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            var groupItem = document.createElement("li");
            groupItem.className = "list-group-item";

            var groupLink = document.createElement("a");
            groupLink.href = "#";
            groupLink.className = "menu-item";
            groupLink.setAttribute("data-toggle", "collapse");
            groupLink.setAttribute("data-target", "#subSubMenuAuth" + i);
            groupLink.setAttribute("onclick", "showContent('groupContent', " + i + ")");
            groupLink.innerHTML = "GROUP-" + i + " <span class='arrow'>&#9660;</span>";

            var subMenu = document.createElement("ul");
            subMenu.id = "subSubMenuAuth" + i;
            subMenu.className = "list-group list-group-flush collapse";

            groupItem.appendChild(groupLink);
            groupItem.appendChild(subMenu);

            authMenu.appendChild(groupItem);

            // Her grup için bir alt öğe oluştur
            //var subItem = document.createElement("li");
            //subItem.className = "list-group-item";
            //var subLink = document.createElement("a");
            //subLink.href = "#";

            //subLink.setAttribute("onclick", "showContent('deviceContent', " + i + ")");
            //subLink.innerHTML = "Alt Öğe " + i;
            //subItem.appendChild(subLink);
            //subMenu.appendChild(subItem);
        }


    }



    function saveContent() {
        // Get values from the form
        var ipAddress = document.getElementById("ipAddress").value;
        var port = document.getElementById("port").value;
        var devCount = document.getElementById("deviceCount").value;
        var communucationType = document.getElementById("comType").value;
        var deviceType = document.getElementById("deviceType").value;
        var deviceAddress = document.getElementById("deviceAddress").value;

        // Perform actions with the values (e.g., save to database, update UI, etc.)
        console.log("Group ID: " + groupId);
        console.log("IP Address: " + ipAddress);
        console.log("Port: " + port);
        console.log("Device Count " + devCount);
        console.log("Communucation Type: " + communucationType);
        console.log("Device Type: " + deviceType);
        console.log("Device Address: " + deviceAddress);


        // Update the menu item text with IP & Port information
        var groupMenuItem = document.querySelector('.menu-item[data-target="#subSubMenuAuth' + groupId + '"]');
        if (groupMenuItem) {
            groupMenuItem.innerHTML = "GROUP-" + groupId + " (" + ipAddress + ":" + port + ") <span class='arrow'>&#9660;</span>";
        }



        // Create device items based on the device count
        var deviceCountInput = document.getElementById("deviceCount");
        var deviceCount = parseInt(deviceCountInput.value);
        createDeviceItems(deviceCount);


        


        // Bu fonksiyon, seçilen cihaz türüne göre özel metni döndürür


        // Bu fonksiyon, deviceType değerini güncelleyerek createDeviceItems fonksiyonunu çağırır.


    }

    function createDeviceItems(count) {
        // Clear existing device items
        var deviceMenu = document.getElementById("subSubMenuAuth" + groupId);
        if (!deviceMenu) {
            console.error("Device menu not found!");
            return;
        }

        deviceMenu.innerHTML = '';

        // Create new device items based on the count
        for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            var deviceItem = document.createElement("li");
            deviceItem.className = "list-group-item";
            deviceItem.setAttribute("data-target", "#deviceTarget" + i);

            var deviceID = "deviceID_" + i;
            console.log("Device ID:" + deviceID);

            var deviceLink = document.createElement("a");
            deviceLink.href = "#";

            // Get dynamic values from form elements
            var deviceType = document.getElementById("deviceType").value;
            var deviceAddress = document.getElementById("deviceAddress").value;

            deviceLink.innerHTML = deviceType + "(" + deviceAddress + ")";
            deviceLink.setAttribute("onclick", "showContent('deviceContent', '" + deviceID + "')");

            deviceItem.appendChild(deviceLink);

            var deviceMenuItem = document.querySelector('.menu-item[data-target="#deviceTarget' + deviceID + '"]');
            if (deviceMenuItem) {
                deviceMenuItem.innerHTML = deviceType + deviceID;
            }

            try {
                deviceMenu.appendChild(deviceItem);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error adding device item:", error);
                console.log("deviceItem:", deviceItem);
                console.log("deviceMenu:", deviceMenu);
            }
        }
    }





    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var authGroupCount = document.getElementById("authGroupCount").value;
        createAuthorizationGroups(authGroupCount);
    });

    document.getElementById("btnSave").addEventListener('click', function () {
        var authGroupCountInput = document.getElementById("authGroupCount");
        var authGroupCount = parseInt(authGroupCountInput.value);
        createAuthorizationGroups(authGroupCount);

    });

    document.getElementById("btnCreate").addEventListener('click', function () {
        var deviceGroupCountInput = document.getElementById("deviceCount");
        var deviceGroupCount = parseInt(deviceGroupCountInput.value);
        createDeviceItems(deviceGroupCount);

    });






</script>
```

```css
    body {
        display: flex;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }

    .container-fluid {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .menu {
        width: 250px;
        background-color: transparent;
        padding: 20px;
    }

        .menu a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #495057;
            display: block;
            padding: 5px 0;
        }

            .menu a:hover {
                color: #007bff;
            }

        .menu .list-group-item {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

            .menu .list-group-item:hover {
                background-color: #e9ecef;
            }

            .menu .list-group-item.active {
                background-color: #007bff;
                color: #fff;
            }

            .menu .list-group-item .arrow {
                float: right;
            }

    .content {
        display: none;
    }

        .content h5 {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

    .form-group {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Sol Taraftaki Menü -->
    <div class="menu">
        <div id="treeMenu">
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <a href="#" class="menu-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#subMenuAuth" onclick="showContent('authorizationContent')">
                        Authorization Device Groups
                        <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="subMenuAuth" class="list-group list-group-flush collapse">
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <a href="#" class="menu-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#subSubMenuAuth1" onclick="showContent('groupContent')">
                                GROUP-1
                                <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul id="cihazAuth" class="list-group list-group-flush collapse">
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="menu-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#deviceTarget" onclick="showContent('deviceContent')">
                                        CİHAZ
                                        <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <a href="#" class="menu-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#subMenuCPU" onclick="showContent('cpuContent')">
                        CPU Groups
                        <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="subMenuCPU" class="list-group list-group-flush collapse">
                        @*<li class="list-group-item">
                                <a href="#" class="menu-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#subSubMenuCPU1" onclick="showContent('groupContent')">
                                    GROUP-3
                                    <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span>
                                </a>
                                <ul id="subSubMenuCPU1" class="list-group list-group-flush collapse">
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Alt Öğe 3.1</a></li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Alt Öğe 3.2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>*@
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>


        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Sağ Taraftaki İçerik Bölümü -->
    <!-- AUTH CONTENT-->
    <div class="content" id="authorizationContent">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Explanation:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter explanation"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Authorization Device Group Count:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter count" id="authGroupCount">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">CPU Group Count:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter count" id="cpuGroupCount">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-end">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave" onclick="saveContent()">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- GROUP CONTENT-->
    <div class="content" id="groupContent">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Communication Type:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <select class="form-control" id="comType">
                    <option>TCP/IP</option>
                    <option>Serial Port(COM)</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">IP & Port:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="IP Address" id="ipAddress">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">:</div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Port" id="port">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Device Count:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Device Count" id="deviceCount">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-end">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave" onclick="saveContent()">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Device Content-->
    <div class="content" id="deviceContent">
        <h5>Device Count</h5>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Device Type:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <select class="form-control" id="deviceType">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>ABC1</option>
                    <option>ABC2</option>
                    <option>ABC3</option>
                    <option>ABC4</option>
                    <option>ABC5</option>
                    <option>ABC6</option>
                    <option>ABC7</option>
                    <option>ABC8</option>
                    <option>ABC9</option>
                    <option>ABC10</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Device Address:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Device Address" id="deviceAddress">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row checkbox-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Options:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="disableCheckbox">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="disableCheckbox">
                        Disable this device
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-end">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnCreate" onclick="saveContent()">CREATE</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

As you can see, the GROUP number increases according to the entered value. Afterwards, when you click on the group option in the menu, an input page appears. If you enter the IP and Port values we entered and click on the save button, these values will be reflected in the GROUP expression in the menu (for example, GROUP-1 (192.168.....: 3333)) in the submenu according to the "device count" number. The element, namely device, is formed. When you click on the Device option, an input screen appears again. The device name value and address value we selected on this screen should be reflected in the menu. For example, " ABC1 (35)". What happens here is that when you select the device and press the "CREATE" button, it is not reflected in the menu, but when you select the device and press the "SAVE" button on the GROUP page, it is reflected, but the result is as I show you in the screenshot. A selected device is reflected in the entire device menu. This should not be the case, each device should have a separate input page so that the value selected for each device is different (as in the screenshot).

[image: Now, its like this]

[image: But it should be like this]